# gettid() returning the same value for two different threads?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a program written by my professor (I modified it a bit to test stuff). From what I understand, on a Linux system:

1. user threads cannot take advantage of a multicore system while kernel threads can. Since pthread can take advantage of a multicore system, it's a kernel thread
2. `gettid` returns the id assigned by the kernel and should be unique since the threads run on different cores; `pth_self` returns the id within the process

I expected to see 2 different values for `gettid`, but this is what I got:

Code:

```
void *count(void *arg) {
    printf("pth_self : %d gettid() : %i \n", pth_self(), gettid());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pth_init();
    pth_t t1, t2;
    t1 = pth_spawn(PTH_ATTR_DEFAULT, count, &a);
    t2 = pth_spawn(PTH_ATTR_DEFAULT, count, &a);
    pth_join(t1,NULL);
    pth_join(t2,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
pth_self : 23023312 gettid() : 45868 
pth_self : 23090368 gettid() : 45868
```

Why is gettid returning the same thing for the 2 threads? I also got a warning about some kind of "implicit declaration of gettid" if that's important.

Thanks

Comment: Add `#define _GNU_SOURCE  #include <unistd.h>  #include <sys/types.h>` to avoid warning.  [ref](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html)

Comment: `%i` may be incorrect for `gettid()`.  Suggest `printf("pth_self : %lld gettid() : %lli\n", (long long) pth_self(), (long long) gettid());` to avoid type mis-match issues.

Comment: Is the first `count` terminating before the second `pth_spawn`, which then re-uses the old tid?

Comment: Your program is packed full of calls to non-standard functions and uses of non-standard data types.  It's unclear, then, how we can shed any light on the program's behavior, unless by guessing.

Comment: However, there does seem to be at least one misconception expressed in the question prose.  Pthreads ***are not*** kernel threads in the sense of the thread ID returned by `gettid()`.  `pthread_t` objects live in userspace, and pthreads functions are user functions, not kernel functions.  But they *use* kernel threads to implement their behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing [pthread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) and [pth](https://www.gnu.org/software/pth/pth-manual.html).

The first use `clone` and `futex` system call (see [here](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pthreads)). The threads are known by the kernel and can take profit of SMP system.

The second does all in user space: The kernel see only one thread, so `gettid()` will return the same value in all 'thread'.

You may ask "Why pth exists if it doesn't create real threads?"

The answer is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/pth/pth-manual.html#the_compromise_of_pth):

> Pth increases the responsiveness and concurrency of an **event-driven application**, but NOT the concurrency of number-crunching applications.

---

To have different tid values for different thread, you'll have to change your code to:

```
/* compile with -pthread */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>

/* see NOTES of https://linux.die.net/man/2/gettid for explanation */
#define gettid() syscall(SYS_gettid)

void *count(void *arg) {
    printf("pthread_self : %ld gettid() : %li \n", pthread_self(), gettid());
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pthread_t t1, t2;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, count, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, count, NULL);

    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
pth_self : 140492392244992 gettid() : 4422 
pth_self : 140492383852288 gettid() : 4423
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bZDRSsMwFIbv8xSHDSUt3aK93MQ778a8mCKCMEKatpEsKcnp2BDfxWfxwazpWraVLZCQ/Oc/3zknYlII0TRjZYSuMwkPHjNlp@UjOUm1UUEdan7vWdiCa30ZwH0l/VCusHSSHyCExeClhOXzy9Pq98fmUCJWfsaYVqbeTTMlp0Yi23DDUlZIRJVBbh3IXaW54aisgZiRcSZzZSR0DhpB3w9dva/WnRgRsrUhOxa2Nki7O3dFBF8EwqqcMpjTUehu7aXOYQY3OjsR26eCDzNKoB/gYKNRcvRE8wPJSaydgeXrYjEn34QELmy4MrS9hIoiAVFyB3Fbfnus30MR8D4BTOdkIItwoqS3bbAlB0Y7R/foC1940@vegfnThs4C9QqnC6XnoX62uzBY0/yJXPPCN5O38NXNpE/7Bw)

Answer (score 0):

You have an overflow error, making the result meaningless.

your code with int overflow:
printf("pth_self : %d gettid() : %i \n", pth_self(), gettid());

correction:
printf("pth_self : %ld gettid() : %ld \n", (long)pth_self(), (long)gettid());

With the usual default linux compile, pthread_self(), is 8 bytes, and int is 4, pthread_t would be 8 bytes.